# Why is my site being blocked by firewalls (like FireEye and Symantec)?

Tags: firewall

In heavily locked-down corporate networks (like utilities) my visitor chat website is being blocked and/or reported as phishing by network firewalls like FireEye and Symantec.

The website is secure, running over the standard HTTPS port (443).

The website is not blocked by personal, community or most corporate networks.

I've seen a screenshot of the reported error, but not enough detail to understand what's going on technically.

I have gone to both FireEye and Symantec and do not see a way to test the site.
I have also tested it against Google Phishing (it is not on the list) and some other smaller 3rd parties, none of which report issues.

My question: IS THERE A PLACE TO TEST to get more detail about potential pitfalls to research and address?

[image: Reported Error]

Comment: Sorry but the question is too specific and recommendations on 3rd party web apps considered off-topic.

Comment: I will add... your site is not secure over HTTPS since you have mixed content due to the fact new visitors get your `<div class="logo"></div>` which uses a background image using `HTTP://` not `HTTPS://` in your CSS under `.css-jjidt3-Logo > .logo`, also various javaScript refferences `fileStoreUrl: "http://cdn.ramblechat.com"` -- time to fix the basics.

Comment: A technical question about why my technical site is experiencing an issue is "too specific?" What in the world are you talking about? Isn't "how do I get a PHP substring?" exactly the same type of question? Of course it is - and it helps me and others.

Comment: Sorry I understand your disappointed but I recommend that you visit our help centre before wasting any more, you may be able to savage your question by editing it, making it less specific in regards of 'your' site, the not asking for recommendations to where online you can test your site and including additional about the firewalls since they can be both software and hardware based and come in many different versions. If you wish to discuss your closure then please visit our meta.

Comment: It's not "disappointment," it's irritation. This is simply wrong. I see questions all the time about "give me your code snippet." There is nothing more specific to a single problem then a code snippet. In this question, my equivalent code snippet is my website address. And your concept of ignoring recommendations for "3rd party web apps" is asinine - this means nobody should mention Google's Web Master Tools? or the W3C code validator? Your designation as a moderator may need to be re-evaluated...it looks like you have been doing this for too long.

Comment: The question topic is phrased in a way that is general. The topic and body are searchable for other people looking for similar issues. Searches of this topic, by the way, bring back very few, all unhelpful links - meaning the issue needs to be solved (I find it hard to believe I'm the only one who has had this problem). Sad, you're denying helping people on the web. Unintentionally, I'm sure, Nobody gets 20,000 points because they DON'T want to help folks.

Comment: The question has been locked because comments are reserved for other purposes and not disputing closure reasons. I have tried to be helpful and it seems you have formed a barrier of resentment. I feel there is nothing more I can say on the subject or at least a response that would resolve this issue, I, therefore, recommend you visit our [META](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/), by doing so you can post a  ***constructive appeal*** about the closure of your question and why you think it should be allowed, this would be reviewed by the other moderators of Pro Webmasters.

Comment: @SimonHayter is correct - comments really shouldn't be used for the [discussion of community behavior or site policies](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). The OP asked a question about this on the Meta site [here](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/how-could-this-question-be-improved) however, which is the proper thing to do when you want to discuss why your question was put on hold.